# Auto-prefix selected SLF4J logged messages

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I'd like messages logged from a testing library to be auto-prefixed with "TEST" so they are easier to highlight or filter from the primary output.

Libraries: [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) / [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)

I'd prefer this as a feature of the logging rather than making every test class have to implement something special it although I wouldn't be against making them all apply a consistent [Marker](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Marker.html) if that helps.

1. How can certain loggers be intercepted and prefixed?
2. Is there a way that doesn't involve a test-only log config file?

Comment: Just attach a certain formatter to the package containing the tests.

Comment: Sounds so simple :) Care to demonstrate?

Comment: That really depends on how you configure logback, but [this page](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) should show everything you need.